# Can't Install Vect2D

Tags: python, module

I'm following a `pygame` tutorial, and in it, you need to use multiple different modules. I was able to download all of them, except this one called `Vec2D`. When I try to run it in command prompt, it gives me this:

[image: Here's an image.]

This is really weird because it gives no output - the module isn't set up and I don't get an error. When I try to test it later, it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: Is that the usual command to install Python modules?

Comment: @aryamccarthy I'm new to python. so how would you install it?

Comment: What does the tutorial say about it? Seems like you've already downloaded it from somewhere other than pip.

Comment: @aryamccarthy The tutorial doesn't tell you how to download the modules

Comment: So you've not downloaded the module yet? Python packages usually contain a file called `setup.py` which you can use to install them. Download the module then try `python setup.py install`. You would make our life easier by linking to the tutorial...

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis the tutorial is here:http://pet.timetocode.org/

Comment: Oh right, so he's written his own module, called `vec2d_jdm.py` containing a class called `Vec2D`. So you don't need to install it, just make sure the file is in the same folder as the code you're running and `from vec2d_jdm import Vec2D` at the top of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructor has written his own module, called `vec2d_jdm.py` containing a class called `Vec2D`.

You don't need to install it, just make sure that the file `vec2d_jdm.py` is in the same folder as the code you're running and `from vec2d_jdm import Vec2D` at the top of your code where you import everything else (such as `pygame` I imagine).